Combining search results from multiple WP_Query objects in WordPress
I'm working on a WordPress project where I need to perform a search across multiple post types and taxonomies, and then display the combined results. I've created separate WP_Query objects for each post type and taxonomy, retrieved the IDs of the posts returned by each query, and merged them into a single array. However, I'm having trouble creating a final WP_Query object using the combined IDs.
I've tried this so far, but we doesn't have any results.

function data_fetch() {
    check_ajax_referer('data_fetch_nonce', 'security');

    $keyword = isset($_POST['keyword']) ? sanitize_text_field($_POST['keyword']) : ''; 

    $page_query = new WP_Query(array(
        'fields' => 'ids',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        's' => $keyword,
        'post_type' => 'page',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'tax_query' => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'page_category',
                'field' => 'slug',
                'terms' => 'zabiegi',
            ),
        ),
    ));
    
    // Query for your custom post type
    $custom_post_type_query = new WP_Query(array(
        'fields' => 'ids',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        's' => $keyword,
        'post_type' => 'uslugi', // Replace with your custom post type slug
        'post_status' => 'publish',
    ));
    
    // Concatenate posts arrays
    $combined_posts = array_merge($page_query->posts, $custom_post_type_query->posts);
    
    // Create final query
    $combined_results = new WP_Query(array(
        'post__in' => $combined_posts,
    ));

    // Merge the results
    $combined_results = new WP_Query();

    if ($combined_results->have_posts()) {
        echo '<div class="search-results">';
        while ($combined_results->have_posts()) {
            $combined_results->the_post();
            echo '<div class="search-result-item">';
            echo '<div class="search-result-wrapper d-flex">';
            echo '<div class="result-content">';
            echo '<p class="result-title"><a class="p c-heading" href="' . esc_url(get_permalink()) . '">' . get_the_title() . '</a></p>';
            echo '</div>';
            echo '</div>';
            echo '<div class="result-action">';
            echo '<a class="result-content p c-heading f-500" href="' . esc_url(get_permalink()) . '">Przejdź' . '<svg class="result-mini-icon c-def" width="16" height="16" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                <use xlink:href="#arrow-down-tiny"></use>
            </svg></a>';
            echo '</div>';
            echo '</div>';
        }
        echo '</div>';
        wp_reset_postdata();
    } else {
        echo '<p class="no-results">Nie znaleziono zabiegu.</p>';
    }

    wp_die();
}

However, the final query doesn't seem to be returning the expected results. Can anyone help me understand what I'm doing wrong or suggest a better approach for combining and querying the search results from multiple WP_Query objects in WordPress?

Can you please post a sample of what you expect to get and what you are actually getting? I think the problem might be in what you're passing to the new WP_Query when you make $combined_posts with array_merge. The result should be a plain array of numerical ids, while you're actually making a collection / array of objects (since that's what the posts are). You could extract the post IDs with wp_list_pluck().

You probably need to specify both posttypes in the merged query args like so 'post_type' => ['testimonial', 'uslugi', 'page'], - otherwise wp will query the post__in IDs in the default type post. You may not need a new WP_query as get_permalink() and get_the_title() also accept pos ids as arguments.

'post_type' => 'any' should also work - "retrieves any type except revisions and types with ‘exclude_from_search’ set to true." (quote docs)

You can use multiple queries with UNION clause
Eg:
global $wpdb;
$result = $wpdb->get_results("(SELECT ID from wp_posts p WHERE p.post_type = 'post') UNION (SELECT ID from wp_posts p WHERE p.post_type = 'page')", OBJECT);

